# Any approximate date we will have Monero wallet with graphical user interface?

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui

What is the approximate date we will have a Monero wallet with graphical user interface?

Comment: There is no announced release date. People have been speculating about the release date on Reddit for the past year.

Comment: Here's a demo of one I'm working on: http://webm.land/media/UpHh.webm

Answer (score 7):

2 weeks from now.

(now = whenever you look at this)

Comment: You dropped this: (>")>™

Answer (score 5):

As @ginger-ale alluded to, I'm about 2 weeks away from having a working prototype for mine: http://webm.land/media/UpHh.webm

More information is available at http://moneybit.science :)

Answer (score 4):

I saw somewhere a picture with the beta GUI. It looked very very nice. But i dont know if it was fake or not.

Moreover there is a third part GUI here: https://www.monerowallet.com/#/gui

Comment: https://www.monerowallet.com/#/gui is not a third party GUI. It is an unofficially compiled (by a community member who did not create the wallet) version of the official GUI now in development.

Comment: @seekadventure note that this unofficially-compiled GUI is missing some of the latest development features and is only for Mac